# Unable to type into any AllocConsole windows

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue with typing into my console window after I injected it into a process. I have tried std::getline and std::cin with no results. After using them it's like the program just ignores them and continues on. Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    std::string commands[] = {
        "cmds","test","test2"
    };
    std::string input;
    printf("To see a list of commands type 'cmds' and press enter\n");
    std::cin >> input;
    if (input == "cmds") {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(commands); i++) {
            printf(commands[i++].c_str());
        }
    } else {
        if (input == "test")
        {
            printf("This is a test");
        }
    }
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        main();
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: The functions you are allowed to call in `DllMain` are quite restricted and I suspect none of those are on the list.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Both freopen and AllocConsole work. Does stuff inside of main() count too?

Comment: You reassigned stdout but not stdin nor stderr.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! I am pretty new to this so

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. And get the idea for this

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<std::string, 3> commands{ "cmds","test","test2" };

    std::cout << "To see a list of commands type 'cmds' and press enter\n" << std::endl;
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    if (input == "cmds") {
        for (int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << commands[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (input == "test")
        {
            printf("This is a test");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't fix the issue but it makes it prettier. It seems that both Visual Studio 2015 Community edition & Dev-C++ 5.11 skip the cin completely